# Pandas groups the data and counts, including a value of 0

Tags: python, pandas

When I group and count the data, it will only show the number of existing values, which can be displayed intuitively, but I can't use it.
My data:

```
name    group
aa  a
aa  b
bb  a
cc  b
dd  a
dd  b
```

My code：

```
df=pd.read_csv(fp6)
a=df.groupby(['name','group'])['group'].size()
```

result:

```
name  group
aa    a        1
      b        1
bb    a        1
cc    b        1
dd    a        1
      b        1
```

If I extract its value to draw a chart, it will prompt me that I have missing parameters.
I want to show all 'group' values for each 'name'.
like this:

```
name  group
aa    a        1
      b        1
bb    a        1
      b        0
cc    a        0
      b        1
dd    a        1
      b        1
```

Can someone teach me?

Comment: Are you assuming that all the names are going to have all elements in group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A really explicit way to ensure having all combinations is to use [`Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html) data (conversion can by made using [`pandas.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html)).

*NB. I added here a group **'c'** in the categories **that is non represented** in the data to illustrate this point.*

```py
df['name'] = pd.Categorical(df['name'], categories=['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd'])
df['group'] = pd.Categorical(df['group'], categories=['a', 'b', 'c'])

df.groupby(['name','group'])['group'].size()
```

output:

```
name  group
aa    a        1
      b        1
      c        0
bb    a        1
      b        0
      c        0
cc    a        0
      b        1
      c        0
dd    a        1
      b        1
      c        0
Name: group, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `pd.crosstab`:

```py
>>> pd.crosstab(df['name'], df['group']).stack('group')
name  group
aa    a        1
      b        1
bb    a        1
      b        0
cc    a        0
      b        1
dd    a        1
      b        1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```py
df = df.groupby(['name','group']).count().unstack(fill_value=0).stack()
```